# Type 'Observable<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<UserRegistration>'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-http, angular-httpclient, angular-observable

```
register(email: string, password: string, firstName: string, lastName: string,location: string): Observable<UserRegistration> {
    let body = JSON.stringify({ email, password, firstName, lastName,location });
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "/accounts", body, options)
      .map(res => true)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

I found this code online, and i'm trying to implement it in my own project, but i keep getting the follow error:

```
Type 'Observable<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<UserRegistration>'.
  Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'UserRegistration'.
```

it also uses this class:

```
export interface UserRegistration {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName:  string;
  location: string;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your method shows , you are returning a boolean true , while your definition says it should return **`Observable<UserRegistration>`**. Change your method return type as,

```
register(email: string, password: string, firstName: string, lastName: string,location: string): Observable<boolean>
```

However your logic does not seem to be right as it always going to return true.

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty obvious. You told Typescript you expect from the method to return an observation of `UserRegistration` while you mapped and returned your result to `Boolean` on this line of code:

```
.map(res => true)
```

According to your code - if there an error won't be thrown from the http request, then map the result to "true" and return it.

Just change the value from in the first line from `Observable<UserRegistration>` to `Observable<boolean>`

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

Your map statement is returning true:

```
return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "/accounts", body, options)
  .map(res => true)
  .catch(this.handleError);
```

I assume you really want to be returning the observable. If so, you don't need to map it.

What version of Angular and RxJS are you using?

If you are using the current version of Angular (v7) then it should look like this:

```
return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "/accounts", body, options).pipe(
  catchError(this.handleError)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are returning with UserRegistration  object then, use below code.
I have altered little

```
register(email: string, password: string, firstName: string, lastName: string,location: string): Observable<UserRegistration> {
    let body = JSON.stringify({ email, password, firstName, lastName,location });
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "/accounts", body, options)  
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

your return type is `Observable<UserRegistration>` but you're returning a `boolean`
you should either change the return type to `Observable<boolean>` or return an object of type `Observable<UserRegisteration>`

Welcome to Stackoverflow:)